# What are the right hooks in Ember.js to implement a "loading" state in a route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

While a Position model loads, I want to show a loading/spinner message in the template. I am not being able to achieve that.

```
{{#if loading}}
  <div class="spinner"></div>
{{else}}
  <div>Here goes the position</div>
{{/if}}
```

Given the router

```js
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('article', { path: '/:id' }, function() {
    this.route('position', { path: '*position_id' });
  });
});
```

my approach in the `ArticlePositionRoute` is the following:

```js
App.ArticlePositionRoute = Em.Route.extend({

  actions: {
    loading: function() {
      var controller = this.get('controller');
      if (controller) controller.set('loading', true);
      return false;
    }
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('loading', false); // BEFORE _super
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('loading', false); // AFTER _super
  },

  model: function(params) {
    return promiseThatTakesAWhile(); // slow fetch model
  },

  afterModel: function(model) {
    var self = this;
    return promiseThatTakesAWhile().then(function(result) {
      model.set('result', result);
      self.set('controller.loading', false); // THIS THROWS "Uncaught Error: Property set failed: object in path "controller" could not be found or was destroyed."
    });
  }

});
```

In `afterModel`, the controller is not available, throws `Uncaught Error: Property set failed: object in path "controller" could not be found or was destroyed.`

In `setupController`, when the `set` goes **before** the `_super` call, it blows with `Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('loading', false) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.ArticlePositionController:ember726>: its 'content' is undefined.`, if I put it **after** the `_super` call, the view already calls `didInsertElement` and errs because it can't find the right `div` in the template (basically, it's too late).

**What are the proper hooks to set/unset the 'loading' flag?** I think I have the `set loading true` in the right place, but I don't know where to put `set loading false`.

When [the Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/) say `actions: { loading: function(transition, originRoute) { // displayLoadingSpinner(); ...`, if that example in the docs was fully developed, what would it look like?

Comment: Isn't the loading template meant for this? You could create a template called `position/loading` and it'll render when the route is loading.

Comment: I have that in place for the Application, I tried for Position but it doesn't do anything (adding the `position/loading` template as you suggest) . When I check the routes in the Ember inspector Chrome extension, Ember is recognizing loading routes for Application and Article (i.e. `LoadingRoute` and `ArticleLoadingRoute`) but not for Position. Why?

Comment: Maybe you need to add an ``{{outlet}}``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the built in loading route.  You may think it needs to exist as a child route of the resource that is taking time to load, but that's incorrect, it needs to be a child route of the parent's resource (which will have already resolved).  Or in your case the loading route needs to exist as `ArticleLoadingRoute`.  It will be shown any time any resource/route immediately under it is taking time to load.

Here's an example where I've forced two resources to take a while to load

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/465/edit

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I believe I wrongfully tried `ArticlesLoadingRoute` (misspelling)

Comment: It would be great to know though how to utilize the right hooks, in case the logic required goes beyond a simple template. Any idea how "displayLoadingSpinner()" would be implemented, as suggested in the Ember guide  at http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/ ?